# Why did Christ wash Judas feet in John 13:5?

Tags: christology, peter, judas

John 13:5 (NKJV)

> 5 After that, He poured water into a basin and  began to wash the disciples’ feet, and to wipe them with the towel with which He was girded.

Christ clearly states that one of them will betray him,but he goes on & washes all their feet.

Since Christ had indicated earlier on to Peter the significance of washing feet

Why did he still wash Judas feet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus does not explain on that occasion *why* He is washing the Apostles' feet, but He tells Peter, *What I am doing you do not understand now, but you will know after this* (John 13:7).

The understanding here is that Jesus was teaching a lesson in humility.  Theophylact explains:

> "You do not yet understand that I am teaching you humility.  But *after this* you shall see Me ascending into heaven ... Then *you will know* that He Who humbled Himself and washed your feet is the same One Who ascended into heaven ... Then you will understand that My power and majesty are not diminished in the slightest when I display humility.  Having learned that humility elevates one to the heights, you too will embrace it."<sup>*</sup>

Given that Jesus' purpose in washing the Apostles feet was to demonstrate His humility toward man, I do not think His declining to wash Judas' feet along with the others' would have accorded with this purpose.  After all, He had the power to decline crucifixion, but submitted Himself not only to the one who betrayed Him but even to those who committed the physical act, even begging forgiveness for them as they were in the midst of committing it (Luke 23:34).

---

<sup>*</sup> <sup>*Explanation of the Holy Gospel According to St. John* (tr. from Greek, Chrysostom Press, 2007), p.212</sup>

Answer (score 4):

St. John Crysostom gives an insightful commentary on this scene; his conclusion was that it was to convince Judas not to betray Him, to give him occasion to reconsider his intentions freely, and not by compulsion, by offering him a gesture of the uttermost kindness and humility (though God—cf. *Phil 2:5-11*):

> ... Let us see also what He does now towards the disciples, or rather what actions He now exhibits towards the traitor. The man whom most of all there was reason to hate, because being a disciple, having shared the table and the salt, having seen the miracles and been deemed worthy of such great things, he acted more grievously than any, not stoning indeed, nor insulting Him, but betraying and giving Him up, **observe in how friendly sort He receives this man, washing his feet; for even in this way He desired to restrain him from that wickedness.** Yet it was in His power, had He willed it, to have withered him like the fig-tree, to have cut him in two as He rent the rocks, to have cleft him asunder like the veil; **but He would not lead him away from his design by compulsion, but by choice. Wherefore He washed his feet;** and not even by this was that wretched and miserable man shamed.
>
> —*St. John Chrysostom, [Homily 70](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/240170.htm), 1.*

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

The interchange between Jesus and Judas during the Passover celebration is very powerful. The timeline of events during the supper is critical to understand the answer to your question.

If proper comparisons are made between the Synoptics and John's Gospel it becomes clear that the foot washing event happened early in the evening. Maybe one of the first things, even before the eating of the meal, but certainly before the institution of the bread and cup is established.

The Footwashing is a symbol of humility and servanthood, which is an important lesson Jesus wants to leave with His disciples who have been arguing continuously about, "who among them is the greatest" -- even at this very event they were bickering.

The interesting part of this narrative is that if followed to it's end in John's account you realize that Judas was not present when Jesus actually instituted the Eucharist, which makes sense since unbelievers are not permitted to partake.

The difference with Judas being allowed to have his feet washed was that Jesus wanted to set the precedent for all His disciples, that they were to humbly serve all mankind -- believer and unbeliever alike.

Answer (score 0):

Judas had fixed the deal to betray Jesus. At the table, when Jesus announced that one of them was going to betray him Judas was troubled, he feared getting caught. If Jesus was not captured, Judas's very own life was in danger by betraying the Jewish theocracy.

There was fear in Judas' heart. Was his cover blown? Should he return the money? Should he keep it? He was walking on thin ice. He wanted to betray Jesus discreetly, without anyone knowing.

Jesus felt Judas' turmoil and washed his feet. By washing his feet, the Lord put Judas at peace. Judas was reassured that his cover was not blown and went on to fulfil the scriptures in Isiah by betraying Jesus.

Only Jesus has the power to put the evil ones at ease, that they're not being watched. They can go about their crafty schemes until judgement day comes.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Make sure you take our [tour]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why does Jesus wash Judas' feet?  I do not think we get the full answer in the immediate context, however I think the answer is revealed in other passages as we learn about God's love for sinners and relentless desire to save them.

> Say to them, ‘As I live!’ declares the Lord God, ‘I take no pleasure
>   in the death of the wicked, but rather that the wicked turn from his
>   way and live. Turn back, turn back from your evil ways! Why then will
>   you die, O house of Israel?’ EZ. 33:11 NASB
>
> Do I have any pleasure in the death of the wicked,” declares the Lord
>   God, “rather than that he should turn from his ways and live? EZ 18:23
>
> 9 The Lord is not slow about His promise, as some count slowness, but
>   is patient toward you, not wishing for any to perish but for all to
>   come to repentance. 2 Peter 3:9
>
> 10 Then it happened that as Jesus was reclining at the table in the
>   house, behold, many tax collectors and sinners came and were dining
>   with Jesus and His disciples. 11 When the Pharisees saw this, they
>   said to His disciples, “Why is your Teacher eating with the tax
>   collectors and sinners?” 12 But when Jesus heard this, He said, “It is
>   not those who are healthy who need a physician, but those who are
>   sick. 13 But go and learn what this means: ‘I desire compassion, and
>   not sacrifice,’ for I did not come to call the righteous, but
>   sinners.” Matt 9:10
>
> But Jesus was saying, “Father, forgive them; for they do not know what
>   they are doing.” And they cast lots, dividing up His garments among
>   themselves. Luke 23:34

Answer (score 0):

Jesus washed Judas's feet in order to follow righteousness. Jesus allowed himself to be baptised by John similarly, to follow righteousness. He fed bread to the children, to follow righteousness. In other words, He needed to follow the letter of the law, before following the spirit of the law. Jesus did not need to be baptised, but Jews who showed fruit worthy of repentance had to be baptized for Israel to be taken back into the covenant. The children were made vessels of dishonor, but they needed to be allowed to reject the bread, in order to manifest, expose, their disobedience, so that all would receive mercy, be saved by grace.

What was the letter of the law in Judas's case? Since all who showed fruit worthy of repentance could not be denied baptism, Judas was baptised. Similarly, when he confessed that Jesus was the Messiah, he would have been baptized in Christ's name. Going forward, when he gave up all he had, Jesus would have washed his feet. Outward action is responded with following of righteousness, the letter of the law. Judas may not have meant any of his actions, internally, spiritually, he may have been unclean, unfaithful, but his outward acts needed a lawful response.

Answer (score 0):

JESUS WASH THE FEET SO THAT HIS DISCIPLS LEARN TO BE MODEST ..BUT

1-WHAT GOOD IS WASHING JUDAH'S FEET ..JESUS WAS TEACHING HIS DESCIPLES TO BE MODEST ..JESUS KNEW THAT JUDAH WILL DIE THE VERY SAME NIGHT ..THEREFORE NO POINT OF WASHING THE FEET. THERE IS NO BENEFITS
2- FOR SURE JESUS DID NOT WASH JUDAH FEET ...THERE IS NO BENEFIT
3- JESUS CHOOSE JUDAH TO BE ONE OF HIS DESCIPLS .HE KNEW THAT JUDAH IS THE DEVIL HIMSELF .(NOT ONE WHO IS POSSESSED WITH DEVIL) .JESUS KEPT JUDAH UNDER OBSERVATION FOR THE PURPOSE OF HANDING OVER JESUS TO THE PHARISIS .AND TO SHOW HIM GOD;S POWER AND GLORY .JESUS DID NOT ORDER OR DIRECTED JUDAH DIRECTLY OR INDIRECTLY TO DO SO ..BUT WITHOUT JUDAH'S PLANNING TO HAND OVER JESUS IN THE NIGHT ..JESUS MIGHT NOT HAVE BEEN CAUGHT THAT PARTICULAR NIGHT ,IN ANOTHER WORD JESUS GAVE THE DEVIL CHANCE TO DO THE DIRTY WORK WITH JESUS APPROVAL AND CONSENT, NOBODY OTHER THAN THE DEVIL HIMSELF WILL DARE TO HAND OVER JESUS TO HIS ENEMIES FOR HE WAS ADMIRED AND LOVED BY THE CROWD .. , JESUS LATER TOLD PILATUS ,,THE ONE WHO HANDED ME TO YOU HAS A GREATER SINS ,THE PHARISIS WERE PLANNING TO GET JESUS AFTER THE HOLIDAY ,,WHICH CONTRADICT JESUS'S PLAN ..HE WANTED TO BE DURING THE HOLIDAY FOR HE IS THE LAMB FOR THE PASSOVER ..IT CAN NOT BE AFTER THE HOLIDAY ..
4- JUDAH NEVER WAS AFRAID THAT HE IS BEEN CAUGHT ..OTHERWISE HOW HE HAD THE GUTS TO COME IN THE OPEN WITH THE GUARDS AND KISS JESUS AND WITNESS HIS ARREST WITHOUT EVEN TRYING TO DEFEND JESUS AS ONE OF HIS DISCIPLS LIKE PETER DID ..

MY QUESTION IS ...WHAT  DID JUDAH EXPECTED AFTER JESUS ARREST ..AND WHY HE WAS SURPRISED THAT THEY CONDEMED JESUS TO DEATH ..?? FOR THAT QUESTION I HAVE NO ANSWER ..

BELLA HANNA

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please, kindly, in your next post be good enough to write in normal, lower case lettering ( as all the other questions and answers). Writing in capitals is considered to be akin to 'shouting' in text and it is to be discouraged. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is very clear that Jesus washed the feet of the diciples because they were dirty.

No not physical dirt though that was probably the case too but there actual path was filthy.

Judas was going to betray him. Peter was going to deny him. And the others were going to be no where to be found.

They all were abandoning him aka their feet were quick to flee but were supposed to stand with him if they were righteous...

Comment: When you have a moment, please take our Tour to understand how we are different to other sites and what constitutes a good answer: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Jesus washed all of The Twelve's feet because "he loved them to the end". In other words, He loved each of them with perfect righteousness. God loves the world with a compassion and common grace (John 3:26, Matthew 5:44-45, Titus 3:4) but He loves 'His own' with a special saving grace.

We see in John 13:2 that the devil already put the thought of betrayal into Judas Iscariot's mind. In John 13:27 we see that Satan himself possessed Judas Iscariot and Jesus said to him, "What you are going to do, do quickly" and He dismissed Judas from the room so that he would go betray Him. Since we know that only God is omnipotent and that those who are truly Christ's own cannot be possessed by the devil or have him put thoughts into their mind, the appropriate conclusion is that Judas was never a true disciple of Jesus. Even after washing all of The Twelve's feet and explaining the symbolism of washing their feet, Jesus makes a point to say "And you are clean, but not every one of you", referring to Judas, "for He knew who was to betray Him; that was why he said, "Not all of you are clean" (see John 13:10-11).

The reason Jesus washed Judas' feet before he was dismissed was Jesus' perfect love that even shows humility and compassion (common grace) towards unrepentant sinners. As others had said, washing their feet also provided an example for his disciples to humbly serve all.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. I recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score -3):

Interesting question because it may impact the idea of a [water baptism regeneration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptismal_regeneration) that some have taught for centuries.  To be clear, prior to Christ's resurrection, they had only gone through the baptism of repentance.

Anyway, the Lord and disciples are at the meal; Judas Isacariat is present.  Jesus gets up, washes their feet, returns to the meal, announces that one will betray Him, dips the bread, and hands it to Judas.

The OP asks, why wash Judas' feet?

> Jesus replied, "The one who has bathed needs only to wash his feet, but is completely clean. And you disciples are clean, but not every one of you."

In other words, they had been baptized (cleansed), but either Judas had not been baptized by John or had been, but to no effect.  Washing feet would not cleanse him, nor would eating the bread bring him to the kingdom.

As another mentioned, there was also the lesson of humility, of service to be taught and learned.

Comment: This comment assumes that water baptism is a requirement for 'salvation' and there are a total of about 2 verses read without the context of the entire NT can make it seem this way.  A great way to really dig into this is to ask the question: "when does a person receive the indwelling Holy Spirit?  1 verse makes it seem like it's at baptism (Acts 2:38) but Acts 10 proves this not the case as well as every other reference of when it's declared a person receives the Holy Spirit.